# Whenever I save a .NET file I have open in my browser and my code editor, it says the file is in use with another program

Tags: .net

I work in Homesite usually, and have Firefox open with the same file I'm working on so I can periodically refresh the page and check my work (pretty standard).  Whenever I'm working on an .aspx file, it says I can't save it in Homesite because "this file is currently in use with another program".

I usually have to tab away from that page in the browser to save the file in my code editor.  I don't seem to get this message ever when working in PHP, Coldfusion, etc.  Anybody ever experienced something similar?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Some process has an open handle to your file. The tool I use for troubleshooting this is [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) - it will show you what program has got the handle (by using "Find Handle"), and it's good for lots of other stuff, too.